# Don't trigger an expansion in Ultisnips

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

Sometimes I want Ultisnip not to expand a snippet because I need this word as it was typed, even though is mapped to a snippet(of course in a perfect world of perfect snippets this wouldn't have happened).

I need to press `ESC` and 2 times `u` and even so it doesn't work sometimes. Any other way?

Comment: Have you tried literally inserting the character that causes the expansion by using control-V? Doesnt Ultisnips require you to hit a « trigger » first?

Comment: I assume the OP is talking about snippets with autotriggering (`:h UltiSnips-autotrigger`). Afaik, the answer is no. However, I could imagine a toggle function to disable autotrigger in UltiSnips snippets temporarily. There is a closed related issue [#874](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/874) on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following code, just in case:

```
nmap <D-I> :let @z=input('enter text: ') <bar> norm "zp<CR>
```

Simply, type new text to be inserted , where it is not effected by i-mappings or Ultisnip.

Comment: Simplified: `:put =input(...)<CR>`

Comment: No, put doesn't work character wise the same way.

Comment: Well sure but since youre hacking around a bizarre case anyway

Comment: pressing `Ctrl-V` does not work?

Comment: Maybe, but it is also useful for mapping such as jk. And it takes longer to do ctrlv.